# select last 5 elements from an element collection using :gt() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider that, i had selected all `tr` elements from a `table` which contains 10 rows, now from that i just tried to filter out the last 5 elements by using the following way

```
var xTrs = $('tr');
var xLastTrs = xTrs.filter(':gt('+ (xTrs.length - 6) +')');
```

Now the above snippet is working fine when i am having more than 5 rows in that table, but when the scenario becomes like, the table is having only 5 rows, the selector get validated as `xTrs.filter(':gt(-1)');` and it is refusing to fetch the expected result.

what i am doing wrong here..? I thought `:gt(-1)` would select all the elements which is having index from 0 to 4 in that context. Please correct me if i am thinking in a wrong way.

And by the way, first tell me how can we achieve that by using `:gt()` and after that let me know some other efficient ways.

Comment: you can put a check if table has more than 5 rows and then call your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) supports negative indices

> negative index: Zero-based index, counting backwards from the last element.

```
var xTrs = $('tr');
var xLastTrs = xTrs.filter(':gt(-5)');
```

so does slice

```
var xLastTrs = xTrs.slice(-5);
```

Comment: @Reigel seems like it is selecting the last 4 elements, so the selector should be like this `:gt(-6)` Anyway thanks. Have a look at the recently posted answer seems interesting.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Test if `xTrs.length` is more than `5` before filtering:

```
xLastTrs = (xTrs.length <= 5) ? xTrs ? xTrs.filter(':gt('+ (xTrs.length - 6) +')');
```

Comment: Fine, i just came to know about a new function called `Math.max()`, but this would return 0 whenever the evaluated result get down below 0, so that i selector would get evaluated as `:gt(0)` so in the context i explained, it would skip out the first element and selects the last 4 elements only...

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var xTrs = $('tr');
var xLen = xTrs.length - 5;
var xLastTrs = xTrs.filter(':eq('+ xLen +'),:gt(' + xLen + ')');
```

Clever isn't.?

Comment: Surely `:gt(' + (xLen - 1) + ')` would be better performance wise?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yeah but this suits for my context. `:gt(-1)` will be wrong but greater than or equal to zero will be right.. Am i right..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yeah, you're right. `:gt(-1)` would take the last element.